# How to use the backslash operator in Julia?

Tags: operators, julia, backslash

I am currently trying to invert huge matrices of order 1 million by 1 million and I figured that the Backslash operator will be helpful in doing this. Any idea as to how it's implemented?. I did not find any concrete examples so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

> Any idea as to how it's implemented?

It's a multialgorithm. This shows how to use it:

```
julia> A = rand(10,10)
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.330453  0.294142  0.682869  0.991427   …  0.533443  0.876566   0.157157
 0.666233  0.47974   0.172657  0.427015      0.501511  0.0978822  0.634164
 0.829653  0.380123  0.589555  0.480963      0.606704  0.642441   0.159564
 0.709197  0.570496  0.484826  0.17325       0.699379  0.0281233  0.66744
 0.478663  0.87298   0.488389  0.188844      0.38193   0.641309   0.448757
 0.471705  0.804767  0.420039  0.0528729  …  0.658368  0.911007   0.705696
 0.679734  0.542958  0.22658   0.977581      0.197043  0.717683   0.21933
 0.771544  0.326557  0.863982  0.641557      0.969889  0.382148   0.508773
 0.932684  0.531116  0.838293  0.031451      0.242338  0.663352   0.784813
 0.283031  0.754613  0.938358  0.0408097     0.609105  0.325545   0.671151

julia> b = rand(10)
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0795157
 0.219318
 0.965155
 0.896807
 0.701626
 0.741823
 0.954437
 0.573683
 0.493615
 0.0821557


julia> A\b
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
  1.47909
  2.39816
 -0.15789
  0.144003
 -1.10083
 -0.273698
 -0.775122
  0.590762
 -0.0266894
 -2.36216
```

You can use `@which` to see how it's defined:

```
julia> @which A\b
\(A::AbstractArray{T,2} where T, B::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T) in Base.LinAlg at linalg\generic.jl:805
```

Which leads us here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/generic.jl#L827 (line numbers change slightly because of version differences). As you can see, it does a few quick function calls to determine what type of matrix it is. `istril` finds out of its lower triangular: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/generic.jl#L987 , etc. Once it determines the matrix type, it specializes the matrix as much as possible so it can be efficient, and then calls `\`. These specialized matrix types either perform a factorization which then `\` does the backsubstitution (which is a nice way to use `\` on your own BTW to re-use the factorization), or it "directly knows" the answer, like for triangular or diagonal matrices.

Can't get more concrete than the source.

Note that `\` is slightly different than just inverting. You usually do not want to invert a matrix, let alone a large matrix. These factorizations are much more numerically stable. However, `inv` will do an inversion, which is a lot like an LU-factorization (which in Julia is `lufact`). You may also want to look into `pinv` for the psudo-inverse in some cases where the matrix is singular or close to singular, but you should really avoid this an instead factorize + solve the system instead of using the inverse.

For very large sparse matrices, you'll want to use iterative solvers. You'll find a lot of implementations in [IterativeSolvers.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/IterativeSolvers.jl)

Comment: A 10^6 x 10^6 dense `Float64` matrix takes 7.3 terabytes of RAM. Since inverting a sparse matrix produces a dense matrix, you don't actually want to invert your matrix. This is a good rule of thumb: don't invert, solve.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm working with the backslash operator now. I'm also trying out the inv() call it but it gives me stackoverflow error. I searched for a mechanism to put some limit on the system RAM to be used by julia (My system has a RAM of 1TB)  I wonder whether we have such language constrains in julia.